# How to correctly scale and normalize (x,y) coordinates from one window size to another

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I am creating a chat program that allows users to freely move their avatars around a chatroom. When the program is first loaded the default chat window size is (996,496), which is the smallest size the window can be. The user is able to adjust the size of the program, so this window will resize based on their preference.

I am trying to ensure that each client is able to correctly render the placement of user avatars, regardless of the other users screen size. Ultimately, the goal is to have all of the avatars in their approximate positions across all of the clients.

In order to accomplish this, I have come up with the following solution when repositioning an avatar in the client:

- Normalize the (x,y) coordinates of the current avatar as a percentage between [0,1]. In this scenario the relative coordinates of (0,0) = top left corner of the room window and (1,1) would be the bottom right corner of the room window.
- I want to use these normalized (x,y) coordinates to place the avatar in the correct position of the client's room window for their particular window size.
- In this scenario if the new x coordinate is > room window width then I will set the new x coordinate to be (room window width - avatar width). Likewise, if the new y coordinate is > room window height then I will set the new y coordinate to be (room window height - avatar height). This should prevent the avatar from going outside of the viewable room area

This approach almost worked, but I ran into a problem where if the room window resized to a larger size on the client, then the avatar would not update its position correctly. For example, if I placed an avatar in the bottom right corner (relative position of 1,1) and then maximized the room window, the avatar did not move to the bottom right corner like I would expect.

In order to try and fix this problem I added a scaling factor. My assumption was to use (new room size / original room size) to figure out the scale. This did make the avatar try to go to the correct position after the room window was increased, but the actual new coordinate values were smaller than the expected values, so the avatar didn't get exactly where it needed to. Additionally, when the room window is increased, the avatar now goes to the wrong position when it is moved to any part of the room except for a corner.

You can see the code I wrote to try and implement this here:

```cs
    int avatarX = roomUser.UserAvatarX; // current X coordinate
    int avatarY = roomUser.UserAvatarY; // current Y coordinate
    int avatarWidth = roomUser.UserAvatar.Width; 
    int avatarHeight = roomUser.UserAvatar.Height;
    int roomWidth = FrmClient.formClient.WebBrowser.Width; // Client room width
    int roomHeight = FrmClient.formClient.WebBrowser.Height; // Client room height
    int originalRoomWidth = 996;
    int originalRoomHeight = 496;

    // Compute the scale factor to account for difference in room sizes
    double scaleX = roomWidth / (double)originalRoomWidth;
    double scaleY = roomHeight / (double)originalRoomHeight;

    // Compute the X coordinate as a percentage of the room width
    double relativeX = avatarX / (double)(roomWidth - avatarWidth);

    // Compute the Y coordinate as a percentage of the room height
    double relativeY = avatarY / (double)(roomHeight - avatarHeight);
   
    // Calculate the actual X coordinate based on the percentage, room size, and scale factor
    int actualX = (int)(relativeX * (roomWidth - avatarWidth) * scaleX + 0.5);

    // Calculate the actual Y coordinate based on the percentage, room size, and scale factor
    int actualY = (int)(relativeY * (roomHeight - avatarHeight) * scaleY + 0.5);


    // Adjust the avatar position if necessary
    if (actualX + avatarWidth > roomWidth)
    {
      actualX = roomWidth - avatarWidth;
    }

    if (actualY + avatarHeight > roomHeight)
    {
      actualY = roomHeight - avatarHeight;
    }

    // Update the position of the avatar control in the room
    roomUser.UserAvatar.Location = new Point(actualX, actualY);
```

Here is a concrete example of the results I am getting versus what I am expecting:

- When the room window size is: (996,496)
- I expect the bottom right corner to be the normalized position of (1,1) (works)
- I expect this to translate into the bottom right corner being: (796, 296) (works)

So far the program works like I expect. I can even freely move the avatar around in any part of the room window without any issues. However...

- I now resize the room window to: (1495, 663)
- I expect the bottom right corner to be normalized to a position of (1,1) (works)
- I expect this to translate into the bottom right corner being: (1295, 463) and so I would expect my avatar to now move to this new location, but it does not. (failed)
- What actually happens is that my avatar is being placed at the location (1195, 396) instead of going to (1295, 463). In fact, with the increased window size, anytime I move the avatar anywhere within the room, the avatar keeps going to the wrong location.

Lastly, here is a list of the corners each normalized coordinate pair should correspond to, just to give a more concrete idea of how I am trying to normalize the coordinates:

```
> (0, 0) = top left
> (0, 1) = bottom left
> (1, 0) = top right
> (1, 1) = bottom right
```

Comment: To avoid any information loss i would consider an approach where all calculations are done on the avatar's "logical" position (that is for example the center point of the avatar) and only apply the offset necessary to make it not overflow at the very last step before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with hardcoded test values, with scaling of the avatar dimensions included:

```
int avatarX = 1395; // current X coordinate
int avatarY = 563; // current Y coordinate
int avatarWidth = 100;
int avatarHeight = 100;
int roomWidth = 1495; // Client room width
int roomHeight = 663; // Client room height
int originalRoomWidth = 996;
int originalRoomHeight = 496;

// Compute the scale factor to account for difference in room sizes
double scaleX = roomWidth / (double)originalRoomWidth;
double scaleY = roomHeight / (double)originalRoomHeight;

// Compute the X coordinate as a percentage of the room width
double actualX = avatarX * scaleX;

// Compute the Y coordinate as a percentage of the room height
double actualY = avatarY * scaleY;


double scaledWidth = (double)avatarWidth * scaleX;
double scaledHeight = (double)avatarHeight * scaleY;

// Adjust the avatar position if necessary
if (actualX + scaledWidth > roomWidth)
{
    actualX = roomWidth - scaledWidth;
}

if (actualY + scaledHeight > roomHeight)
{
    actualY = roomHeight - scaledHeight;
}

// assuming there is a set accessor:
roomUser.UserAvatar.Width = scaledWidth;
roomUser.UserAvatar.Height = scaledHeight;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. It suffers from the exact same issues as the code I shared. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I tested it with sample values, and it does give the correct answer as I understand it. I edited my answer by pasting the code with the hardcoded sample values. Perhaps the problem is with how you are retrieving the window size, or the effects of zoom or magnification in the browser or OS

Comment: I ran your follow up code and it gave me the same values as my original code:   `int avatarX = 796, int avatarY = 296, int avatarWidth  = 200, int avatarHeight = 200, int roomWidth = 1495, int roomHeight = 663, int originalRoomWidth = 996, int originalRoomHeight = 496` I get (1194, 395) but I expect (1295, 463).

Comment: It's because the avatar dimensions don't scale. It is being repositioned correctly in relation to the top left corner, but the distance from the bottom right corner is now greater than the size of the avatar.  A simple solution would be to scale the avatar dimensions as well as move it. Would that be acceptable? Otherwise you would need to consider when you would want to reposition it in relation to the bottom right instead of top left etc.

Comment: I am not opposed to scaling the avatar. I am just not really sure how to do that. Could you possibly show me an example of that and how I could work it into my code? Thank you very much for all of your help so far.

Comment: Okay, I've added code to scale the dimensions of the avatar as well.

Comment: I tried this method out and it does not work. I have the avatar scaling correctly and fixed a bug where the avatar keeps growing when it is moved. However, even with the larger avatar size, when I move the avatar around the room, it is buggy and jumps all over instead of moving to the location I dropped it at. There is definitely some underlying problem with the scaling, because the values are still not returning what I would expect.

Comment: You'd need to look at the width and height set accessors on the avatar class.

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct some calculations:

```
// Compute the X coordinate as a percentage of the room width
//NO    double relativeX = avatarX / (double)(roomWidth - avatarWidth);
// avatarX: last coordinate (pixel) before a size change
double relativeX = avatarX / (double)previousRoomWidth;
//Same for relativeY
double relativeY = avatarY / (double)previousRoomHeight;

// Calculate the actual X,Y coordinates based on the percentage and new room size.
int actualX = (int)(relativeX * roomWidth);
int actualY = (int)(relativeY * roomHeight);
```

All of it is for the case where the window is resized without seeing new things on the left. I mean, no X,Y origin is changed.

For example, if origin is changed to `noX, noY` then the last two lines must be

```
int actualX = noX + (int)(relativeX * roomWidth);
int actualY = noY + (int)(relativeY * roomHeight);
```

Note that scale factors are not needed. They may be if you want your avatars to be resized too.

In order not to position the avatar +/-1 pixel perhaps you want to store `avatarX, avatarY` into `double`'s, and convert them to pixels (`int`) just in the function they are drawn.

Comment: Okay, this was actually a really good suggestion. Now it works almost exactly like I want. However, there is one problem I can't get to fix. If I go from a smaller screen size to a larger screen size, it works perfect. However, if I go from smaller to larger back to smaller, the avatar placement is a little off only on the x-axis when I am in the top right or bottom right corner.  The crazy thing is if I start from max screen size, it works 100% of the time. Any suggestion on how I could correct this?

Comment: That seems a precision issue. In my last suggestion I told about using doubles. Other also good way is that "previousWidth/Height" is always the first size of the window, not the last one. Because you work with normalized (0-1 range) data, accuracy is always best.